# C++: Unpack a tuple with references and values without copying/moving too much

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, tuples, move-semantics

Let's say I have a tuple `t` whose type is `std::tuple<T1,T2,T3>` where each `T` may be either `Obj`, `Obj&`, `Obj&&`,`const Obj&`. I want to write a function which unpacks the values of the tuple into a function `f` which accepts three types that decay to `Obj`. I want to avoid useless copying as much as possible, how I do it?

My current implementation is

```
static R call(C2&& c, TUP&& x) {
using TUP0 = typename std::remove_reference<TUP>::type;
return c(std::forward<typename std::tuple_element<0, TUP0>::type>(std::get<0>(x)),
         std::forward<typename std::tuple_element<1, TUP0>::type>(std::get<1>(x)),
         std::forward<typename std::tuple_element<2, TUP0>::type>(std::get<2>(x)));
}
```

But this implementation seems to `move` things when `TUP` is `std::tuple<Obj,Obj,Obj>`, even though it should only move when TUP contains an `Obj&&`.

Comment: But I want to unpack it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `std::forward` will cast a non-reference type to an rvalue reference. You want a function that will cast a non-reference type to an lvalue reference but preserve the reference category if the type is already a reference:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) stable_forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& arg) {
    return static_cast<std::conditional_t<std::is_reference<T>::value, T, T&>>(arg);
}
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) stable_forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&& arg) {
    return static_cast<std::conditional_t<std::is_reference<T>::value, T, T&&>>(arg);
}

static R call(C2&& c, TUP&& x) {
    using TUP0 = std::remove_reference_t<TUP>;
    return c(stable_forward<std::tuple_element_t<0, TUP0>>(std::get<0>(std::forward<TUP>(x))),
             stable_forward<std::tuple_element_t<1, TUP0>>(std::get<1>(std::forward<TUP>(x))),
             stable_forward<std::tuple_element_t<2, TUP0>>(std::get<2>(std::forward<TUP>(x))));
}
```

Apologies for C++14, the transformation to C++11 is left as an exercise to the reader.

I've answered the question as asked. How wise it is I cannot say. Barry's answer might serve you better if you can adjust your code to supply the tuple as an rvalue.

Comment: Just `std::get<0>(std::forward<TUP>(x))` is already the right thing.

Comment: @Barry Not if `TUP&&` is an lvalue reference. In that case, rvalue reference elements of the tuple would be cast to lvalue references.

Comment: Which is correct. If the tuple is an lvalue, then it's not safe to move from it.

Comment: @Barry You wouldn't be moving from it. You would be moving from the object referred to by its rvalue reference element.

Comment: That's the same thing - you're moving from its members without it being an rvalue.

Comment: @Oktalist why does your `stable_forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&&)` return an lvalue when `!is_reference<T>::value`? (Although a better question would be why did you bother inventing it anyway? It's not necessary)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Good observation, I hadn't considered if the tuple were an rvalue.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: In order to obtain the desired behaviour it is necessary (as the result of `get` is an lvalue in case of the tuple being an lvalue) and I can't think of a reasion why it should not be legitimate to obtain an rvalue reference from an lvalue tuple holding an rvalue reference. (Where the question how an lvalue tuple holding an rvalue reference actually can arise is a different one.)

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, this is known as [`std::apply()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
static R call(C2&& c, TUP&& x) {
    return std::apply(std::forward<C2>(c), std::forward<TUP>(x));
}
```

This can be implemented in C++11 by using the index sequence trick. `std::make_index_sequence` only got added to the standard library in C++14, but it itself is also implementable in C++11 and I will not include that implementation here:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class F, class Tuple, size_t... Is>
    auto apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, index_sequence<Is...>) 
        -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...))
    {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
    }
}

template <class F, class Tuple>
auto apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
    -> decltype(details::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{}))
{
    return details::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{});
}
```

---

There seems to be some confusion with what [`std::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) actually does. Note that it depends on the reference qualification of the tuple. Here are the relevant overloads:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&
    get( tuple<Types...>& t );
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&&
    get( tuple<Types...>&& t );
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >const&
    get( const tuple<Types...>& t );
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >const&&
    get( const tuple<Types...>&& t );
```

The returning type matches the `const` and ref qualifications of the input tuple. That is given a `std::tuple<int> a`, `std::tuple<int&> b`, and `std::tuple<int&&> c`:

```
std::get<0>(a);            // int&
std::get<0>(std::move(a)); // int&&

std::get<0>(b);            // int&
std::get<0>(std::move(b)); // int&, because reference collapsing

std::get<0>(c);            // int&, because reference collapsing
std::get<0>(std::move(c)); // int&&
```

`std::get<I>(std::forward<TUP>(x))` gives you the correct, safe type of reference, regardless of the type of the that member of the tuple. `std::get<0>(c)` gives you an lvalue reference - which is correct behavior. If you want an rvalue reference out, you need an rvalue in. Per usual.

Comment: Care to say how does this handle move-references in the tuple? I understand that it generalizes my solution to N parameters, but this is not what I'm interested in, I'm interested in being able to handle tuples combining both a reference and a non reference

Comment: @tohava `std::get()` will do the right thing if you pass in the `tuple` with the right value category. That's why the `forward` is inside the `get`, not outside. If the tuple is an rvalue, you get a `tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>&&` - which will be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference as appropriate.

Comment: This handles the case where the reference is on the tuple, I am talking abhout the case where the tuple contains references. Please note that the answer above you answers this correctly.

Comment: @tohava [So am I](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f4073397a0d44b5)

Comment: The accepted answer is over-complicated and unnecessary. Using `forward` on the tuple and then `get` does the right thing, as Barry says. Inventing `stable_forward` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think OPs "problem" is that `std::tuple<int&&> c` gives `int&` for `std::get<0>(c)` whereas `int&&` is desired.

Comment: `c` holds an rvalue reference `int&&`. Thus I'm pretty sure there may be use cases where you'd want an `int&&` - no matter whether `c` itself is an rvalue.

Comment: @Pixelchemist The way to do that is `std::get<0>(std::move(c))`.

Comment: @Barry: `c(std::get<0>(std::move(c)), std::get<1>(std::move(c)),...)` seems pretty ugly to me and I'd rather not write that because seeing code where `move` is applied multiple times to the same object is generally rather suspicious.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Right, that's why you wrap this up in `apply(c, std::move(tuple))`.

Comment: `X a{}; std::tuple<X, X&&> t(X{12}, std::move(a));` Now you can do two things: `apply(c, std::move(t));` where `t` will have its first and second element "moved from" or `apply(c, t);` where none of the elements will be moved from. If what you're after is "*move from value elements if the tuple is an rvalue otherwise don't move from them and move from rvalue elements no matter whether the tuple is an rvalue*" then you're out of look with this scheme.

Comment: Right, `std::get<0>(std::move(c))` will move elements that are not references.

Answer (score 3):

If I get the question right, the desired behaviour is: Pass on an rvalue reference only if the element type is "rvalue reference" or if the element type is "value in an rvalue tuple" while otherwise passing on lvalue references.

#### 1. In case of an lvalue `T` = `std::tuple<Obj, Obj&, Obj&&>&` object `tuple`:

- Don't move first element (`Obj`) <sup>1</sup>
- Don't move second element (`Obj&`)
- Move third element (`Obj&&`) <sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: `std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>(std::get<I>(tuple)...)` won't do that job as the result will be `Obj&&`. Also `std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...` won't either give the desired behaviour as the result will again be `Obj&&`.

<sup>2</sup>: Here `std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(tuple))...` won't give the desired value type as the result will be `Obj&`.

#### 2. In case of an rvalue `T` = `std::tuple<Obj, Obj&, Obj&&>&&` object `tuple`:

- Move first element (`Obj`)
- Don't move second element (`Obj&`)
- Move third element (`Obj&&`)

`std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(tuple))...` will do the trick on rvalues.

---

Thus what I think you want is:

```
tuple<Obj>& -> Obj&
tuple<Obj&>& -> Obj&
tuple<Obj&&>& -> Obj&&

tuple<Obj>&& -> Obj&&
tuple<Obj&>&& -> Obj&
tuple<Obj&&>&& -> Obj&&
```

---

While the answer of @Oktalist will give you the desired behaviour, there's another way to do it:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<std::size_t I, class ... Ts>
    decltype(auto) get(std::tuple<Ts...>& x)
    {
        using T = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
        return static_cast<std::conditional_t<
            std::is_reference<T>::value, T, T&>>(std::get<I>(x));
    }
    template<std::size_t I, class ... Ts>
    decltype(auto) get(std::tuple<Ts...>&& x)
    {
        return std::get<I>(std::move(x));
    }
}

template<class C2, class TUP>
decltype(auto) call(C2&& c, TUP&& x) {
    return std::forward<C2>(c)(
        detail::get<0>(std::forward<TUP>(x)),
        detail::get<1>(std::forward<TUP>(x)),
        detail::get<2>(std::forward<TUP>(x)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the question more clearly. The `T&&` in your conditional type is redundant because it's already a reference, so you can just use `T`